# Install only a few GNU coreutils?

Tags: compiling, gnu, coreutils

Is there a way to build and install only a few of the GNU coreutils?

The README in coreutils-8.19.tar.xz lists 100-odd, but the INSTALL doesn't say how to install only a few, and the Makefile is (to me) opaque.

Comment: Not so much an answer as a pointer to an idea - buildroot normally sets up only a subset of coreutils, and if you have a smallish subset, you might want to consider busybox with the relevant tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  ./configure
  cd ./lib
  make
  cd ../src
  make version.h
  make cat
  make ls
```

HTH

===

UPDATE as of February 26, 2015:

The recipe above doesn't work in at least coreutils-8.23. I would not recommended building separate files.

The following shows the complexity of internal dependencies for `cat` and `ls`:

```
./configure
make src/version.h
make lib/configmake.h
make lib/arg-nonnull.h
make lib/warn-on-use.h
make lib/fcntl.h
make lib/sys/stat.h
make lib/selinux/context.h
make lib/selinux/selinux.h
make lib/unitypes.h
make lib/unistr.h
make lib/uniwidth.h
make lib/getopt.h
make src/cat
make src/ls
```

Comment: Thanks @Deer Hunter.  How might a mortal have discovered this, or is it just common knowledge ?

Comment: Trial and error - mostly reading the output from naive attempts to `make chroot` etc. and figuring out the dependencies.

Comment: Now it doesn't work. There's no `Makefile` after `./configure` in `lib` subdirectory.

Comment: Do you know any workaround?

Comment: @enedil - fixed a bit, you can try building `cat`, can't vouch for other utils.

Comment: My real issue is that I try to cross-compile for my rooted android device. My simple C programs compiled on laptop work on tablet, so it's not problematic. But I get some errors while compiling one particular binary from coreutils. What I relly nead is a `GNU ls` copy. That one from Busybox has dirrerent switches. Anyways, I'll check the updated solution.

Comment: @enedil - you have to ask a separate question for that, I'm afraid. Also Android is dealt with on a [separate site](https://android.stackexchange.com), better answers still on http://xda-developers.com, one would guess.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But Android.SE lacks Unix system knowledge. xda is probably a good place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to build only **cat** and **ls**:

```
wget -O- https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-9.1.tar.xz |tar xJf -

cd coreutils-9.1 && mkdir my && cd my && ../configure

echo -e "\nmy: \$(BUILT_SOURCES)\n\t\$(MAKE) \$(AM_MAKEFLAGS) src/cat src/ls" >>Makefile

make my

strip src/cat src/ls
file src/cat src/ls
```